# How to use check_box_tag to pass it to the params hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, input, parameters

So I am looping through an array of movie characters, each of whom has a checkbox. I want it such that when I hit the "Select My Cast" button and I get redirected to the teams_path (index method in my controller) to be able to get the ids of the characters the I had selected in an array in my params hash.

Here's the code:

```
  -@chars.each do |i|
   =image_tag(i.image)
   %br
   First Name:
   =i.f_name
   %br
   Last Name:
   =i.l_name
   %br
   Show :
   =i.show
   %br
   =check_box_tag 'char_ids[]', i.id
   %hr

= link_to "Select My Cast", teams_path, :method => :get
```

I placed a binding.pry in my index method in my controller and params had no char_ids array or any relevant information. Thanks for the help; I realize this a known to many question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controller is not getting the parameters and from your code snippet; it most likely that:

1. You forgot to include a  form tag on your page
2. Clicking on that `link_to` anchor link and not submitting your form.

So, make sure you have your `form_for` or `form_tag` setup and make sure you submitting your form using some kind of "button" and not simply an anchor tag (`link_to`).

**PS.** You don't need to add `method: :get` to your `link_to`, because it is `get` by default.

**PSS.** You can use [`multiple: true`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box#1001-Sending-array-parameters) in your `form_for check_box` to for multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue and it took a while to solve, so I'll post my solution for posterity.

I have a User model with a serialized hash field `messaging_preferences=> { "articles"=>false, "marketing"=>false, "digest"=>false }`

what tripped me up was needing to use the `fields_for` in the form.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :messaging_preferences, user.messaging_preferences do |message_type| %>
    Marketing emails: <%= message_type.check_box :marketing, {}, "true", "false" %><br />
    Article emails: <%= message_type.check_box :articles, {}, "true", "false" %><br />
    Weekly digests: <%= message_type.check_box :digest, {}, "true", "false" %><br />
  <% end %>
```

and update the user_params in your controller to reflect (like so): ``

but with this (and the user_name & email params) generates this call to the server:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"{{token}}", "user"=>{"name"=>"Jimmy Johnny", "email"=>"spam@gmail.com", "messaging_preferences"=>{"marketing"=>"false", "articles"=>"false", "digest"=>"false"}}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"6"}
```

so, here we've got nested params being sent.